# Ionic 4 capacitor video player plugin not found by mainActivity

Tags: android, ionic4, capacitor

I am trying to use the capacitor video player plugin found here for my android project.

https://github.com/jepiqueau/ionic-capacitor-video-player

When running on google chrome it works as desired. However when attempting to run the project on the android emulator on android studio, I run into problems on MainActivity.java

I am getting the following error "Cannot resolve symbol 'jeep'" in the following line

```
     import com.jeep.plugin.capacitor.videoplayer.CapacitorVideoPlayer;
```

I have installed the jeep file, but for reasons unknown to me it cannot find the file.

```
   npm install --save capacitor-video-player@latest
```

I have tried moving the 'jeep' folder around, so mainActivity can resolve the folder, but that leads to more errors down the line, with CapacitorVideoPlayer.java. I feel I am clearly missing a step in the process.

Comment: Did you run npx cap update after the plugin install?

Comment: That did it, thank you

Comment: ok, added as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run `npx cap update` after installing the plugin.

That makes some changes in the native project so it's able to detect the newly installed plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The jeep plugin is not working on android version.
Just initPlayer function is working.
I will update updated new capacitor video plugin soon

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer so once you can comment consider doing that instead.